# What advantages does Redux offer over just creating a class that can be accessed globally?

Tags: angular, redux

So I'm doing some reading into the Redux pattern, and whilst I get how it works, I'm unsure about the exact purpose.

Why wouldn't I just create a service class that is provided on a global scale which every class can set and access.

```
@Injectable()
export class SettingsService {

  constructor() { }

  public MyVariable: number = 20;

}


 <p>
    <label class="label">Adjust my variable</label>
    <input class="slider" type="range" max="150" min="1" [(ngModel)]="settingService.RouteLength" /> {{settingService.MyVariable}}
    </p>
<p>
```

What extra benefit is there in implementing the redux pattern compared to just a class that everyone can access?

Answer (score 3):

Redux is not just a central place to store data. It is one directional flow of data. 
More info here : http://fluxxor.com/what-is-flux.html

I will explain my experience . I believed the same and used `BehaviorSubject` in my service and implemented the code. It was very tedious and confusing.

I use `@ngrx/store` which is similar to `redux` . It gave me these advantages:

1. **Predefined Syntax:**  The syntax is clear and strict . No need to re-invent the wheel, I instantly stopped thinking of architecture
   and went straight ahead with my application logic
2. **Loosly coupled code**: This is life changer for me . In our team
   we could share the task among different developers and each could
   complete their part without any dependency with other developer.
   Unit testing is also independent. We can write service, reducer,
   effects, component + HTML code independently. It is like a miracle.
3. **Redux dev tools** :  Using Redux dev tools, we can go back and forward , check data status etc., it made life easier . We can also
   use it demonstrate the UI. I usually go back in states and show how
   loading page looks like, how error page looks like etc.,
4. **Immutable data** : Because data is updated only at reducers , it is easy to debug the code. Trust me, even with junior developers (with couple of months experience) we don't have any bugs. Its very straight forward.

It looks like a simple idea but made a huge difference in development experience.

Only drawback is the syntax is verbose, but it feels good to see everything working perfectly.